# drag and drop the content from one div to another having same classname and in a sortable manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to drag and drop the content of one div to other div and all the div have the same classname. Also I want to do it in a sortable  manner. In the Html there are many div with similar class and is displayed in multiple column.
 HTML CODE:

```
<div class = "section" style = "padding : 4px;">
       <span class = "display" ><span style = font-weight : bold;>Lion 
      </span></span>
    </div>
    <div class = "section" style = "padding : 4px;">
       <span class = "display" ><span style = font-weight : bold;>tiger 
    </span></span>
    </div>
```

JS code:

```
function dragAndDrop(){
       $(".section").draggable({
          refreshPosition: true,
          drag: function(event,ui){
               ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
          },
          stop:function(event,ui){
               ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");      
          }
         });
        $(".section").droppable({
          drop: function (event, ui) {

         $(this).find("ddsection").addClass("dddroppable").html("Dropped!");
             }
          });
        }
        dragAndDrop();
```

Comment: Some of your html is invalid `<span class = "display" <span style = font-weight : bold;>Lion`

Comment: I  have edited it.

Comment: Still invalid, `<span class = "display" <span` is missing `>` in `<span class = "display"> <span`

Comment: okay. I corrected it

Comment: could you please provide more details? i understand, that you have a page with several divs and want to drag one into another. should the target div only accept dragged divs of the same class, or of any class? what should happen with the original div? should it revert back to it's position, but then be empty? or do you want to pick single parts of the content - in your case the spans to move them from one div to another?

Comment: The target div will accept dragged divs of same class as any other class is not present.Yes ,the spans to move from one div to another

Comment: this doesn't answer my questions. so again - do you want to move all spans of one div at once, or move the spans one by one? what should happen to an empty div? should it stay or vanish?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need jquery sortable to achieve what you want. 
https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists